# RSA encryption theory - modulo theory

Tags: math, encryption, rsa, modulo

I'm a bit mathematically challenged and have been working on the RSA cipher (good start).  I can find the public and private keys and know how to work do modulo operations on a calculator.  The problem is that I can't do them when the numbers get to high.  For example say I have:

```
 10^541 mod 2923 = C
```

The numbers involved here become very large and don't display fully on a calculator, if it can even handle the numbers (mine is crap).  What I am wondering is if there is a better method to work out the ciphertext or plaintext that will work for largish numbers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: This is off-topic here.  But, to answer your question, a computer would do it using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) (and modding after each step, to keep the numbers small).  Also, a good graphing calculator should be able to handle that calculation, even if it can't display the whole number before the mod.

Answer (score 1):

I think http://math.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question.

But, essentially, don't save the `mod` for the end.  Break the exponentiation up into many smaller operations with `mod` after each one.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com could work too.